# How can i rewrite URL IN ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, routes

I have some files under the views of the area "admin", and i want to rewrite the url of some action like "agence" and "agences" without affecting "login", so how can i do it ?
This is a link to a print screen of my project.
http://hpics.li/764e0ea

Comment: It is preferable if you paste the relevant code into the question instead of providing screenshots of text.  There is a risk that external content will disappear from the web!

Comment: @Amranze you can resolve your issue by adding proper route, if you show to us piece of code of how you tried to do this, we will able to help you

Comment: this is the architecture of my project:
Area
----------
   Admin
        -----Controllers
             --->HomeControllers.cs
        -----Models
        -----Views
             -->Login.cshtml
             -->agence.cshtml
             -->agences.cshtml


this is the code of homecontroller

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can solve this issue by creating a new route in your "RouteConfig" file (App_Start -> RouteConfig).

The default route for MVC is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } 
);
```

You can use this as a template for creating a new route as well. Simply place the new route above the "Default" route. Something like the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Any distinct name",
        url: "{controllerName (judging by your question, probably }/{variable1}/{variable2}/{etc... if needed}",
        defaults: new
    {
        variable1 = UrlParameter.Optional,
        variable2 = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

You can then pass your chosen variables as RouteValues in ActionLinks.

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "Action", new { variable1 = whatever, variable2 = whateverElse})
```

Comment: can i add route for area folder ?